# Balance of ERC-20 Token suddenly changing to 0 in try/catch block

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20, truffle-test, try-catch

I'm coding a paymentsplitter that accepts LP tokens and standard tokens. If it's an LP token, it needs to convert them into the underlying assets, otherwise just split the payment. Since I only have access to the address of the token, my idea to determine if it's LP or not was to just call `getReserves()` on a try/catch block and see if it fails:

```
function receiveAndDistribute(uint256 amount, address token) external override {
        require(amount > 0, "Distribution: Amount must be greater than 0");
        
        address WETH = router.WETH();
        IERC20(token).transferFrom(address(msg.sender), address(this), amount);
        IERC20(token).approve(address(router), amount);

        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this)); // Truffle debugger says it's 10

        // Check if token is LP
        try IUniswapV2Pair(token).getReserves() {
            // Remove liquidity code
        } catch {
            uint balanceAfter = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this)); // Now it's 0 according to truffle?!
        }
    }
```

I called it with LP tokens and it works great, the liquidity gets removed. But the problem is when I try to receive something like USDT.

I used truffle debugger to track the variables, and after the try/catch the balance is suddenly set to 0. It's the reason why it also fails on `transferFrom` later in the function code.

I find this extremely weird behavior.

Am I missing something? How is this possible?

EDIT: I simplified the code a little (inside the try/catch) since it is omitted according to the debugger, let me know if I should post the whole thing instead.

Comment: _If it's an LP token, it needs to convert them into the underlying assets_ you seem a bit confused Liquidity Provider (LP) tokens are not the Asset tokens. Liquidity Provider tokens are only used to keep the accounting of how much liquidity the User has put into common pool. The Asset tokens however (like DAI or USDC) is what is converted to one or another during the swapping process.

Comment: if you are doing swaps, you have nothing to do with LP tokens, if I am an external user and I haven't put anything int your liquidity pool (Uniswap v2 pair) , I should be able to do swaps without it. i.e, having liquidity is not a requirement for swapping

Comment: What I mean by "converting them to the underlying asset" is to redeem them using the removeLiquidity function. The contract may recieve LP tokens or asset tokens, the intended functionality is that when it recieves LP it redeems it for the tokens and when it recieves something like DAI it just splits it into the holders

Comment: Basically, the contract needs to have ether. I need to redeem LP tokens if they are supplied to the function. (redeem LP -> swap token0 and token1 for ETH)